# Difference between で and によって

Tags: grammar

Whats the difference between によって and で ?

Example:

台風によって屋根が飛ばされた。
Can I use で in this sentence?-> 台風で屋根が飛ばされた。

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct and natural-sounding sentences.

The difference is in the formality.  「～～で」 would sound more informal or conversational than 「～～によって」.

For that reason, 「～～によって」 is used far more often in writing than in  casual daily conversations.